# Is TWRP OS-version specific?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp

I have a Vsmart Joy 1 phone, running VOS/Android 8.1.0

I found a port of TWRP recovery for Vsmart Joy 1s [here](https://vsfan.vn/threads/twrp-recovery-cho-vsmart-joy-1.285/) ([translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fvsfan.vn%2Fthreads%2Ftwrp-recovery-cho-vsmart-joy-1.285%2F)), but it says "Android 9.0 VOS..."

Does this mean that I should/have to upgrade to VOS/Android 9.0 to be able to use TWRP properly (the end goal is to root the phone)? Or, can I flash it on my phone as is, without upgrading?

Comment: Recovery is an independent OS and it works even if there is no ROM (main OS) installed on device. The code used to build TWRP must have been taken from AOSP 9.0

Comment: Does that mean that I can install it, and it'll work?

Comment: If it's legit then yes, but I found that ported recoveries and roms rarely work, I may be wrong tho.

Comment: Thank you for the response, in the case that it isn't legit, will my phone be soft-bricked or something like that?

Comment: You don't have to install TWRP for starting it. Via `fastboot boot <image name>` you can boot TWRP directly. That greatly reduces the possibility to cause trouble for your device.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm going to try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, TWRP is built OS-version specific

the reason is changes in android versions may differ in

- encryption type
- file system type
- partition layout
- mount point

most (if not all) updates are backwards compatible. that means the TWRP is ready for android 9 but you can still run android 8 on your device

Comment: Could that be why I TWRP is telling me that my password is incorrect?